# What is the correct place to list and examine ports in erl_driver

Tags: c, design-patterns, erlang, libusb-1.0

In [the tutorial](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_portdriver.html) for erl_driver there seems to be no indication to where does the first `ErlDrvPort` object comes from. Say I want to wrap libusb-1.0 to use it from erlang. There is no place in the API described by `ErlDrvEntry` for any index methods. How does one find a port to open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you obtain the first port using the [`erlang:open_port/2` function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2), usage of which is shown in the code example in section 6.2 of [the tutorial](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_portdriver.html) you linked to in your question.

Comment: It looks like they are hardcoding it inside of `driver_entry`. This line: `"example_drv",  /* char *driver_name, the argument to open_port */`

Comment: [Documentation](http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.6/erts-5.6/doc/html/driver_entry.html#extended_marker) is even less specific: `char *driver_name;          /* name supplied as command in open_port XXX ? */`. **XXX ?**

Comment: That string in the driver entry is the name of the driver. It might be helpful to look at a recently-implemented driver, such as [enm, the Erlang nanomsg driver](https://github.com/basho/enm). For example, [enm.erl lines 340-349](https://github.com/basho/enm/blob/master/src/enm.erl#L340-L349) use [`erl_ddll`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_ddll.html) to load the driver shared library, and then [enm.erl line 443](https://github.com/basho/enm/blob/master/src/enm.erl#L443) calls `open_port` to ask the driver for a new port onto itself. (These line numbers are based on enm commit 65f278a.)

Comment: Thank you, i see now. This is more of a design pattern question. In enm library examples the address (Url) is already known. What if you have to rely on the same c library to give you options on what address to use? It seems more natural to use one erlang port per one usb port. But then I would have to use another wrapper for examining usb devices' properties. Or I should use only one port that connects to libusb wrapper and implement some kind of protocol that can list as well as connect and transmit via casting `command` with some magic in first bytes?

Comment: IMO using a control port (your second idea) is the right way to go. You can use `erlang:port_control/3` to implement a protocol to communicate with the driver over such a control port.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Ports to wrap a C library, you can also use [NIFs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html). With [Nifty](http://parapluu.github.io/nifty/) there exists even a wrapper generator that does most of the work for you.

Comment: NIFs are more dangerous, because they can crash entire ErlangVM. For really short well tested code, they might be a good ieda. For wrapping entire library, it is better to stick with ports.

Comment: NIF seems to be a good tool for isolated functions. Like when you need to make some calculations faster.

Comment: Nifty has a "save execution" mode that runs the loaded nif in a separate node. If the library crashes, only the separated node crashes. This also solves the problem of blocking nif calls. (Only the separated node gets blocked)

[relevant Nifty Tutorial page](http://parapluu.github.io/nifty/tutorial5/)